# How to pass method and call it with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have class `CallProtector` that is supposed to call method with variable number of arguments which suppose to protect call via mutex, but I can't figure out how could I pass object's method with their arguments. Here what I have so far:

```
class CallProtector
{
public:

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    void callProtectedMethod(F& lambda, Args... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_guard);
        lambda(args);
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_guard;
};
```

I am trying to use it this way:

```
class Car
{
public:
    void updateEngine(int engineModelType) {}
};

int main()
{
    Car alfaRomeo;
    CallProtector callProtector;
    callProtector.callProtectedMethod(&Car::updateEngine, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

But I have compilation error saying

```
no instance of function template "CallProtector::callProtectedMethod" matches the argument list
```

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might work for you:

```cpp
class CallProtector
{
public:

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    void callProtectedMethod(F&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_guard);
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_guard;
};
```

and then use it like:

```cpp
Car alfaRomeo;
CallProtector callProtector;

auto updateEngine = std::bind(&Car::updateEngine, &alfaRomeo, std::placeholders::_1); 
callProtector.callProtectedMethod(updateEngine, 10);
```

**EDIT**

Or this would work too:

```cpp
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void callProtectedMethod(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_guard);
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

and then

```cpp
callProtector.callProtectedMethod(&Car::updateEngine, alfaRomeo, 10);
```

Comment: It is not working for me, says: 'term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument'. But we could not just forward all the arguments to the std::invoke? Is that any reason for that? It suppose to be very simple, but I really can't figure out.

Comment: what `term`? i think you are not showing us all the code. It works [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6e6nWd) which is msvc

Comment: Thanks, yes, my mistake this code works. But could we avoid doing bind and forward all the arguments?

Comment: I used this code to make it actually work: std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 you can use `std::invoke`, just forwarding all arguments to it:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void callProtectedMethod(Args&&... args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_guard);
    std::invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

also if you want to call member function on Car instance, you have to pass pointer to object.

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aj35MW)

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working for me. Compile error says that: 'invoke' no matching overloaded function found. I am using visual studio 2019 with c++ 17. Also could we do the same with c++ 14?

Comment: @Oleg Why not to make `callProtectedMethod` as function accepting any callable object ? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cPPdbn), passed callable can be created as closure or result of `std::bind` function - there is no problem with passing arguments, just call function with protection of mutex.

Comment: I have to use different objects and pass pointer to it.